# NestJS video stream - progress doesn't work

Tags: html, nestjs

I have a problem with the progress of a video.
There is my NestJS controller (solution form official [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files)):

```
  @Get(':name')
  getFile(@Param('name') name: string): StreamableFile {
    const file = createReadStream(join(process.cwd(), `./uploads/${name}`));
    return new StreamableFile(file);
  }
```

On the client side there is:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source
          src={`http://localhost:3001/api/files/${name}`}
          type="video/mp4"
        />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Video loads correctly. Play/stop, fullscreen works, but I can't change the progress of the movie. Any ideas where is the problem?

Comment: @wozniakluakasz did you find any answer??

Comment: @ShubhamBatra yes, I have used a solution described [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/video-stream-with-node-js-and-html5-320b3191a6b6).